# How do I dynamically add controls on a hierarchical structure using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a form dynamically . I should have `categories` and `subcategories` and `questions` . Here is a simple example where I am adding question elements dynamically:

```js
var i = 1; // to hold increment 

$('#add').click(function() {
    var p = $(this).closest('p'),
        i = $(p).length;
    
    $(p).before('<p> <label> Question ' + i + ': <input type="text" id="question_' + i + '"> </label> </p>');    
    return false; 
}); 

$('#del').click(function() {
   
    $("p label").last().remove();    
    i -= 1;
    return false; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p> <label> Question 1: <input type="text" id="question_1"> </label> </p>
    <p> <a href="#" id="add"> Add Question </a>  </p> 
        <p>  <a href="#" id="del"> Del Question </a> </p> 
</div>
```

How can I add `categories`, so that a `category` can contain multiple `subcategories`, which in return can also contain `subcategories`. Each category should also be able to contain questions. So that my form looks like this :

```
Test Form 

Investment                               // a category
     Real Estate                         // a subcategory 
          How much was spent ?           // a question 
          What is the time frame ?       // a question
     Automobiles                         // a subcategory
     How many vehicles ?                 // a question
What is the total?                       // a question

Charity                                  // a category
How much was spent ?                     // a question
     Donations                           // a subcategory 
          When started ?                 // a question
     Other                               // a subcategory 
          What is the timeframe ?        // a question
```

My current code only creates questions. I tried to create categories but got stuck with the recursion bugs . I tried to read the jtree API but I am not sure it is what I need. I also tried to find a website that would allow to create such a form so that I could take a look at their JavaScript, but could not find such a website. Can someone help me understand how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Alex, that was a pretty awful title edit. If you're gonna edit, try to make the author look BETTER, not worse! Elvis, don't hesitate to roll back unhelpful edits.

Comment: Can you give a little more clarity on what is being created?  Is this entirely in a single HTML page, is there some type of back end that you are interacting with?  What do you expect to happen to the output of the form?  All these things make a difference for what the structure of the generated code would look like

Answer (score 3):

edit:  Second prototype delivered.

The answer really depends on what you're creating "dynamically", which I'm not clear on.  Since I'm not allowed to request clarification until I provide useful answers for rep, here's a jscript that does something useful sorta like what you're saying.

If I really did this myself, I'd integrate an XML file and generate the html entirely from JSON or something.  Or at least populate the initial page from js.  The solution you see here is horribly sloppy and tightly couples the html to the js.

http://jsfiddle.net/P8X3B/109/  (prototype question adder, other controls present, not implemented)

NEW:  http://jsfiddle.net/y29vc5k0/28/  (prototype question and category adder)

```
/**
 ***
 * questions and categories example
 * by Jason D'Aquila
 * 23 Jan 2015
 * created as prototype of answer to stackoverflow question posted at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772009/
 *
 * relies on at least jQuery 1.4 ; browsers supporting getter definitions with Object.defineProperty
 */

/* GLOBAL */
function cleaner(text) {
    var s = text.replace(/(<|>)/g, '\\$1')
        .replace(/ /g, '_')
        .replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, '');
    return s; //can't split a return line
}

/* injective function jQuery objs => String; compact output
 * not actually achieved, but this function isn't called in this program anyway
 */
function injectJQueryObjToStr(jqueryObj) {
    return ("" + jqueryObj.length) + jqueryObj.attr("id") ? " id: " + jqueryObj.attr("id") : jqueryObj;
    //can definitely improve this function
}

canon = ({
    /* contract:  No enumerable property of canon has the name of an html tag
     */
    outputField: $('#out'),
    categoriesList: $('#categories'),

    /* cannot actually canonize this; see below */
    //questionsDropdown:  (function () {  //references must be invocations ofc
    //    return $('#questions_del');
    //}),

    init: function (undef) {
        //*  //single slash comment toggle
        //this.questionsDropDown = (function(nothing) {return nothing;}());
        Object.defineProperty(this, "questionsDropdown", {
            //cannot actually canonize this
            //a setter is only way to "store" a function lookup used with variable access syntax
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: function () {
                return $('#questions_del');
            }
        });
        //*/
        this.init = undef;
        return this;
    }
}).init(); //self-initializing object canon


/*  CLOSURES */
/* referencing contexts:
 * A -- the anonymous function in $('#add') .click 
 * B -- the anonymous function in $('#cat') .click
 */
//referred by:  A, B
var addCategoryIfNotExists = function (desiredName) {
    var category_in = desiredName;
    var f = cleaner;
    //var FF = _compose_ function(x){return 'cat_'+x; } @ cleaner

    if ($('#cat_' + f(category_in)).length) {
        return $('#cat_' + f(category_in));
    } else {

        $("<p></p>").attr({
            id: 'cat_' + f(category_in)
        }).html('<label class="cat_' + f(category_in) + '">' + f(category_in) + '</label>').prependTo(canon.outputField);
        //another option is .clone()

        canon.categoriesList.append($('<option value="' + f(category_in) + '" />'));
        return $('#cat_' + f(category_in));
    }
};

function inputFieldAt(locale) {
    //return $('input', $(locale).closest('p'));
    return $(locale).closest('p').find('input');
}
//consts
var QUESTION_PARENT_ELEMENT_TYPE = "p"; //ideally a preprocessor subs this

/* /CLOSURES */

$('#add').click(
//create closure for i=question #
(function () {
    var i = 1;

    return function () {
        var qid, qidlitl;
        var category_input;
        i = i + 1;
        qidlitl = 'question_' + i;
        qid = '"question_' + i + '"'; //quotes for HTML attr setting

        var category_el;
        //*  //single-slash comment toggle
        //category_input = $('input', $(this).closest('p')).val();
        category_input = inputFieldAt(this).val();
        category_el = addCategoryIfNotExists(category_input);
        //check category_el === canon.outputField.find('#' + 'cat_' + cleaner(category_input) ) 
        /*/
        category_el = document.getElementById("out");
        //*/

        $('<' + QUESTION_PARENT_ELEMENT_TYPE + '></' + QUESTION_PARENT_ELEMENT_TYPE + '>').html('<label for=' + qid + '> Question ' + i + ': </label><input type="text" id=' + qid + '>').appendTo(category_el);
        $("<option></option>").attr({
            "class": "questions_options",
            value: qidlitl
        }).text('Question ' + i + '').appendTo(canon.questionsDropdown);

        return false; //callback contract

    };

})() //SIF to get closure for i = 1 + number of questions ever generated

); //$('#add').click

$('#del').click(function () {
    var qselect = canon.questionsDropdown[0]; //This [0] is the inelegance of mixing frameworks
    $('#' + qselect.options[qselect.selectedIndex].value + '')
        .closest(QUESTION_PARENT_ELEMENT_TYPE).remove();
    qselect.remove(qselect.selectedIndex);

    return false;
});

$('#cat').click(function () {
    //add category and return false exit signal unless add_category returned literal not false (i.e. true)
    var category_input;
    //category_input = $('input', $(this).closest('p')).val();
    category_input = inputFieldAt(this).val();
    var res = addCategoryIfNotExists(category_input);

    //return !!(res && (res === true));  //!! might get eliminated by compiler?
    return res && (res === true) ? true : false; //equality < logical AND < ternary
});

//EOF
```

The html changed slightly.  See the jsfiddle.

So, weeks later, I learn that you actually cannot canonicalize most DOM lookups or jqueries.  Here is a jsfiddle with categories and questions.  The next prototype will have subcategories, and the final answer will let you delete categories and subcategories with no subcategories or questions.

There is a mystery to me in this jscript.  When you add questions, they appear before the one in the html, even though $.appendTo() is used on the containing <\p> .

Comment: Despite working around the clock after I saw this, I was not able to augment the above prototype without introducing some bug that always crashed the <script> environment, even though I had a legal JScript source.  I will continue to work to fix it.

Comment: I don't know why they accepted this answer. But the jsfiddle does not work at all. it's just a piece of c****

Comment: @Alex What browser did you run it on?  Does the add button add <p>s with Question # labels in it?  Does the delete button remove them?

Comment: I am making progress from this prototype, fixing those bugs I mentioned, fixing design errors and mistaken assumptions about API.  But the program I have still (A) is correct JS but (B) doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would design this would be to have a class(by using a constrcutor function) called `"category"` in JS such that it can contain other `"categories"` within itself, maybe in an array. I would make this class also hold a a `questions` array. Now, without thinking about the html too much, I have a nice and clear model of what the world looks like. In the next step, I will write a single function that can take one of these `category` instances and generate the dom. This function `drawCategory` will use a helper function that can probably be an inner function in JS that knows how to generate the dom for a category that does not contain any categories(leaf node in other words), `drawCategory` uses that helper function intelligently and returns the entire dom for a single category instance. Next I simply iterate over how many ever category instances I have and keep passing the category instance to `drawCategory` which automagically does the right thing and returns the right dom each time. To avoid multiple dom updates, I would just generate the dom for each of the categories, hold it somewhere, build the entire dom just once and append it to some target element.